# Calculus 1 The precise definition of a limit by using Graphing Calculator

Tags: calculus

How do you solve this problem in the graphing calculator? 
Im showing the problem and the solution, I need to know the steps on the graphing calculator. I already know how to do it algebraically.
Thanks for your time and for your comments.

[image: Problem]

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the corresponding interval of $x$ ($|x-a|<\delta$, in this case, $|x-2|<\delta$), such that the $y$ value of the function falls into the region $|y-6|<\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon=0.2$, so your region of $y$ is $|y-6|<0.2\Rightarrow 5.8<y<6.2$. This is the vertical region in the graph. Now if you trace from the $y$ value back to the $x$ values, it would give you the boundaries of the $x$ value, i.e., the $x$ values when $y=5.8$ and $6.2$. You can obtain these using your calculator by the "trace" and "zoom in" feature.

In this case, the $x$ values at $y=5.8$ and $6.2$ are, respectively, 1.9774, and 2.0219. Now since you want an interval $|x-2|<\delta$, such that the $y$ values are in the indicated region, $\delta$ should be the smaller one of $2-1.9774=0.0226$ and $2.0219-2=0.0219$, which is $0.0219$. We choose the smaller one since that will ensure the other side of $$|x-2|<\delta$$ would not go out of the boundary, and also since we need a region in which $x$ is at the center.